# How to pass arguments to pre compiled java code

Tags: java, powershell

I need to process a high volume of resumes. And want to use this parser:
https://github.com/antonydeepak/ResumeParser
But you run it in powershell with the file to read and the output file. 
But I do not know how to automate this, so it read a whole folder containing the resumes.

I know some Java, but cant open the code. Is scripinting in powershell the way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course you would be able to change the ResumeParser code, or implement a small script to search for files in your folder structure, I don't know what suits best to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
> java -cp '.\bin\*;..\GATEFiles\lib\*;..\GATEFILES\bin\gate.jar;.\lib\*'
  code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram <input_file> [output_file]
```

Either make a batch file from an edited directory listing, or write a program.
As this is stackoverflow:

So starting with the same classpath (-cp ...) you can run your own program

```
public void static main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File[] files = new File("C:/resumes").listFiles();
    File outputDir = new File("C:/results");
    outputDir.mkDirs();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            String path = file.getPath();
            if (path.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                String output = new File(outputDir,
                        file.getName().replaceFirst("\\.\\w+$", "") + ".json").getPath();
                String[] params = {path, output);
                ResumeParserProgram.main(params);

                // For creating a batch file >x.bat
                System.out.println("java -cp"
                    + " '.\\bin\\*;..\\GATEFiles\lib\\*;"
                    + "..\\GATEFILES\\bin\\gate.jar;.\\lib\\*'"
                    + " code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram"
                    + " \"" + path + "\" \"" + output + "\"");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Check that this works, that ResumeParserProgram.main is reenterable.